# Blink a part of a div with css with the same phases

Tags: html, css, reactjs, less, css-animations

I have a part of div that is intended to blink according to a definite amount of frequency when those items are rendered in a list. Following is the code snippet I have used as the css animation for the blinking pattern.

```
@keyframes blink { 50% { border-color: #f0f2f5; }  }
.statusAnimation {
    border-left: 8px solid @alert-red;
    animation: blink 1.8s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

But the problem here is, each card blinks at its own phase and when multiple cards get rendered at multple intervals, the css blinking happens at various phases which is not very UX friendly.

Is there any way to use keyframes blink to use a specific phase or according to the common date & time seconds frequence or something so that they will use the same phase no matter when they get rendered ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don´t you use `@keyframes`for defining a variable and execute the animation in a element that always exists?, for example:

```
@keyframes blink{
0%{--blink-var: white;}
50%{--blink-var:#f0f2f5;}
100%{--blink-var:white;}
}
.elementThatAlwaysExists{
animation-name:blink;
animation-duration:2s;
animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}
.statusAnimation{
border-color:var(--blink-var);
}
//all the borders will blink at the same time because the variable takes only one value
```